# Phase shift in Voltage- out in an RL frequency response

Tags: voltage

Why is there a phase angle shift approaching 90 degrees for the Voltage -out compared to Voltage-in as frequencies approach zero in a RL circuit's phase frequency response curve? As frequencies increase, this shift decreases to close to zero at high frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have [this circuit](https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2019/07/types-of-passive-high-pass-filters.html): -

[image]

- At low frequencies the inductor is dominant.
- In other words it has a low impedance compared to the impedance of the resistor.
- Therefore the current that passes through the inductor lags the voltage across it by 90°.
- This is all to do with the inductor equation: \$V = L\frac{di}{dt}\$
- This current is sourced from the input signal via the resistor
- This means that the input signal lags the output signal by 90° at very low frequencies
- Put another way; the output voltage leads the input voltage by 90°

At high frequencies the resistor becomes dominant because, the inductor's impedance rises higher and higher with increasing frequency. At very high frequencies the inductor plays virtually no role and can be removed from the circuit hence, the output can be seen to be in-phase with the input.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH FOR YOUR INPUT1

Comment: @proton if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.